# How to handle multiple audiences in auth0

Tags: auth0

I am using Auth0 for authentication purpose and we are using microservices architecture for API's. Can anyone suggest the ways to authenticate the API's since auth0 is not supporting multiple audiences? I am hosting my API's in azure cloud services

Comment: can you please explain a bit more?  so you have number of apis deployed in azure ? you are using auth0 services as identity provider? what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have used a single logical API to authenticate microservices. But the issue is I am able to authenticate only one API(micro service) and the rest of the microservices are throwing an unauthorized error. We have hosted our services in Azure. I am using Auth0 as the identity provider

I have created one API in auth0 and used the same audience for both the micro-services. For the first micro service it is working fine but for the second service, it is throwing an unauthorized error.
Our client application is in angular 6.  
I am trying to implement authorization for microservices

Comment: The token is issued to one of the services. You can use the same token to verify all the services provided you are passing the same token to the other services. Simply in the middle ware you need to verify if your token is valid.

Comment: I have added the middleware to authenticate the tokens. I am able to authenticate the API's when they are running locally in my machine. But when they are deployed on the server I am able to authenticate only the first service for the second service it is throwing unauthorized